# Can you load a file and value into hive at the same time

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to load a file and insert a value at the same time in hive?

I have a simple table team:

```
team_id        int
fname          string
lname          string
new_record     string
```

My load file look like:

```
ID,fname,lname
1,Jimmy,Hendrix
2,bob,marley
3,Richard,sherman
4,Bracia,grimm
```

I want to add a 'yes' if a new team member is added durning a file load, is this possible?? 
If so, what way would I go about writing the query?? Thanks Frostie

Comment: Just map an EXTERNAL table on the file, then run  an INSERT - SELECT query with plain old SQL; the syntax is much more flexible than LOAD i.e. you can change the order of columns, apply functions such as `trim()` or `cast( as )`, add hard-coded values etc.

Comment: For the incremental uploads, a SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS with a correlated sub-query might do the trick. Be careful about the HashJoin memory requirements though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do. 

But what is possible is to load from a existing table and insert at the same time.
so i got around this by using a select and insert